# Changing Value to DataGrid cell

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

I have a function in my code-behind that sets a datagrid.  I create a new blank column and add it to my datagrid and I want to add a value to the column for only one row that matches an object id.  For some reason the cell doesn't store the text I set it to though.  Any thoughts?

```
public void SetContacts(IEnumerable<User> contactList, User reqUser)
    {
        BoundColumn reqColumn = new BoundColumn();
        reqColumn.HeaderText = "";
        dgExistingContacts.Columns.Add(reqColumn);
        dgExistingContacts.DataSource = contactList;

        foreach (DataGridItem row in dgExistingContacts.Items)
        {
            if (row.Cells[0].Text == reqUser.id.ToString())
                row.Cells[6].Text = "Requestor";
        }
        dgExistingContacts.DataBind();

    }
```

Here's my datagrid if that helps:

```
<asp:DataGrid runat="server" ID="dgExistingContacts" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="styledGray" HeaderStyle-CssClass="head" CellSpacing="1" CellPadding="4" GridLines="None" AlternatingItemStyle-CssClass="even" ItemStyle-CssClass="odd">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Id" Visible="false" />
                        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Title" HeaderText="Role" />
                        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Last Name" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" />
                        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" />
                        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Phone" HeaderText="Phone" DataFormatString="{0:(###) ###-####}" />
                        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="EmailAddress" HeaderText="Email" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" />
                    </Columns>
                </asp:DataGrid>
```

I feel like it should be simple but I can't figure out why it's not binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that you have to bind the data before trying to change the contents.  I ended up with this:

```
public void SetContacts(IEnumerable<User> contactList, User reqUser)
{
    BoundColumn reqColumn = new BoundColumn();
    reqColumn.HeaderText = "";
    dgExistingContacts.Columns.Add(reqColumn);
    dgExistingContacts.DataSource = contactList;
    dgExistingContacts.DataBind();
    foreach (DataGridItem row in dgExistingContacts.Items)
    {
        if (row.Cells[0].Text == reqUser.id.ToString())
            row.Cells[6].Text = "Requestor";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see you are adding a column to `dgExistingContacts` and then assign  `contactList` as `DataSource` of  `dgExistingContacts` that means you first add column and then reset `DaraGrid` to former `DataSource` in this code:

```
    dgExistingContacts.Columns.Add(reqColumn);
    dgExistingContacts.DataSource = contactList;
```

I think when you assign a `DataSource` to `GridView`,any thing that you changed in it will be reseted.so maybe by deleting `dgExistingContacts.DataSource = contactList;`from codes, your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try handling the `GridView`'s `RowDataBound` event and adding the value there.